# How to force redirect binding to my available version?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, .net-framework-version

I have this build error:

> Assembly 'Services' with identity 'Services, Version=16.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e1f6866a896162bc' uses 'Directory, Version=2016.5.13.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e1f6866a896162bc' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Directory' with identity 'Directory, Version=12.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e1f6866a896162bc'

I have this in the `web.config`:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Services" publicKeyToken="e1f6866a896162bc" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2016.5.13.8" newVersion="2016.5.13.8" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Why is the binding not picking up the binary as version `2016.5.13.8`?

Other than locating the correct version of the assembly (which I don't think is possible) how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did the method get recompiled?  You need to do a clean build to force code torecompile.  Changing the config doesn't automatically case all methods to recompile.

Comment: I can't recompile the code - it's a DLL which I don't have the source for.